# How to run pandas styler on mac terminal with highlighted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, macos, terminal, pandas-styles

Whenever I run this code on jupyter notebook, it produces the correct highlighted dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)

def highlight_greaterthan(x):
    if x.C > .5:
        return ['background-color: yellow']*5
    else:
        return ['background-color: white']*5 
df.style.apply(highlight_greaterthan, axis=1)
```

However, when I run it in my mac terminal, I received this output:

```
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x118a6e198>
```

I was wondering how I would be able to run this through the terminal and receive the output with the highlighted dataframe. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the IDE. Try printing it.

Comment: Printing it results in the same output: <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x118a6e198>. Does that mean pandas styler would only work in specific ides? It seems like I should be able to at least save the highlighted dataframe but that doesn't seem to work either